# Python copy matrix

Tags: python, matrix, copy

So i have a quick question my code is supposed to delete the row and column (from i and j) which it does but for some reason it also changes the original matrix (while i have copied it). Can someone tell me why that is?

```
def reduce_matrix(M, i, j):
    newM=list(M[:])
    for q in range(len(newM)+1):
        if q==i-1:
            del newM[q]
    for y in range(len(newM)):
        for x in range(len(newM[y])):
            if x==j-1:
                del newM[y][x]
    return newM
```

Comment: Because you say matrix, I am assuming there are lists inside lists and looking at your code, those lists aren't copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy all sublists in a list, instead of copy all list.

try this:

```
def reduce_matrix(M, i, j):
    newM=[k[:] for k in M]
    #rest of code
```

**From your program:**. Try to print `id` of each sublists.

```
def reduce_matrix(M, i, j):
    newM=list(M[:])
    print id(M[0]), id(M[1]), id(M[2])
    for q in range(len(newM)+1):
        if q==i-1:
            del newM[q]
    for y in range(len(newM)):
        for x in range(len(newM[y])):
            if x==j-1:
                del newM[y][x]
    return newM

lis = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[7,4,2]]
print id(lis[0]), id(lis[1]), id(lis[2])
reduce_matrix(lis, 1, 1)

>>>
3074546604 3072046316 3072047084
3074546604 3072046316 3072047084
```

That proves that, sublists are just `tagging or pointing` to another variable.So modification for any sublist will happen to every sublist with same `tags`.

**For example:**

```
a = [1,2]
b = a
c = a
b.append(3)
print a
print b
print c
>>>
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh snap your right just realized the sub lists weren't copied thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

you only copy the first list, not the sublist. 
if you want to return a new matrix with reduce row and column, you can do this:

```
def reduce_matrix(M, i, j):
    return [[M[m][n] for n in range(len(M[m])) if j-1 != n ] \
               for m in range(len(M)) if i-1 != m]
```